# How to match two arrays to form a new array

Tags: java, android, arrays, gridview

In my app i am having some images in drawable folder, same images are used at server.now i am getting an array of 9 image-names from the server and i have to parse the array and fetch images from drawable  folder as the array we got from server and show the images into a grid view.any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Please rephrase. This question is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> String imgName = "ic_launcher";
>   String uri = "drawable/" + imgName;
>   int icon = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable",
>                           getPackageName());

By this, you will get specific image from drawable folder. Iterate your array, and fetch all images from drawable folder.